# "ProgrammingError: column "genre_id" of relation "music_album" does not exist" while the column does exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have the following models :

```
class CulturalDocument(CacheMixin, models.Model):
    ...
    uuid = UUIDField(unique=True)


class Genre(CulturalDocument):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ...

class Album(CulturalDocument):
    ...
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, null=True, blank=True)
```

I added the `genre` attribute with a south migration.

I can see the column `genre_id` in the table `music_album` using pg_admin.

However, when I do this :

```
    album = Album.objects.create(uuid=3,
                                 release_date=datetime(2000, 1, 1),
                                 title="Fantastic Album",
                                 right_holder=rh)
```

I get :

```
 "ProgrammingError: column "genre_id" of relation "music_album" does not exist" while the column does exist
 LINE 1: ..._id", "title", "release_date", "right_holder_id", "genre_id"...
 .                                                            ^
```

Using PostGres 9.2 and Django 1.6 in Ubuntu 12.04.

The generated SQL is :

```
INSERT INTO "music_album" ("culturaldocument_ptr_id", "title", "release_date", "right_holder_id", "genre_id") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

Comment: Does it indeed exists? What is output of `select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'music_album'`

Comment: This returns (0 rows). But 'music_album' does exist since I store data in it and retreive data from it.

Answer (score 7):

Found it !

I got this error running unit tests. When I migrated, I applied migrations on my regular db, but unit tests use a different db.

Py.test, my test tools, was setup to flush tables, but not delete them between tests, for speed up. Therefor the test tables were using the scheme existing before the migration. I just deleted them and force py.test to recreate them.

Comment: Thanks! I ran into this same issue. It's the little things.

Comment: Argh I've been stuck on this for hours, thanks for posting this! :D

Answer (score 0):

Well from what I can see your code:

```
  album = Album.objects.create(uuid=3,
                             release_date=datetime(2000, 1, 1),
                             title="Fantastic Album",
                             right_holder=rh)
```

Is passing 4 elements while table **requires 5** (you are missing genre_id).  Try:

```
  album = Album.objects.create(uuid=3,
                             release_date=datetime(2000, 1, 1),
                             title="Fantastic Album",
                             right_holder=rh,
                             genre_id=VALID_ID)
```

where VALID_ID is valid value for the genre.

Comment: `genre_id` can be null by its definition in model

Comment: It can be null, and the error is that genre_id doesn't exist in 'music_album', not that it's not provided in the query. Just in case I tested with a valid genre, and  got the same error.