# ProgrammingError 'column "scheme_id" of relation "value_calculator_newunit" does not exist' in Django 1.8.3

Tags: python, django, postgresql, linux-mint

After a lot of Googling I haven't been able to find anything that resolves my specific issue. This person's problem [appears similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168582/programmingerror-column-genre-id-of-relation-music-album-does-not-exist-w) to mine, but it's not a migration issue, as `python3 manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python3 manage.py migrate` doesn't resolve the problem (no error messages), nor did resetting the database to an empty state with `python3 manage.py flush`.

The error occurs whenever I create a Scheme without an associated NewUnit or RefurbUnit and try to view or delete it in the admin interface (consequently it becomes undeleteable even in the shell), or when I try to create a new one with a RefurbUnit or NewUnit, in which case it doesn't get created at all.

The project I'm working on is so far not too different to the completed tutorial; the only substantial difference is in views.py for each project's main app. I'll post the error message and the code for both my project's app and for the tutorial's polls app (just for reference, as I can't find an up-to-date pre-completed tutorial project that you can compare my code against):

## Error Message

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/value_calculator/scheme/add/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'value_calculator')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1516.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1468.                 self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_related
  1102.             self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_formset
  1090.         formset.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  640.         return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_new_objects
  771.             self.new_objects.append(self.save_new(form, commit=commit))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_new
  904.             obj.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  710.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  738.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  822.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  861.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  920.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  974.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  658.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/value_calculator/scheme/add/
Exception Value: column "scheme_id" of relation "value_calculator_newunit" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "value_calculator_newunit" ("scheme_id", "D", "f...
                                                ^
```

---

## My app's code

### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Scheme, NewUnit, RefurbUnit

class NewUnitInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = NewUnit
    extra = 0

class RefurbUnitInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RefurbUnit
    extra = 0

class SchemeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #fieldsets = [
    #    (None,               {'fields': ['name']}),
    #    ('Date information', {'fields': ['date']}),
    #]
    inlines = [NewUnitInline, RefurbUnitInline]
    list_display = ("name", "date")
    list_filter = ["date"]

admin.site.register(Scheme, SchemeAdmin)
```

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Scheme(models.Model):
    #scheme_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True) #Makes absolutely no difference.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    new_units = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    refurb_units = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    appraiser = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Nobody", blank=True)

    #FIXME: This method is now broken due to ForeignKeys in NewUnit and RefurbUnit
    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in self._meta.get_fields()]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class NewUnit(models.Model):
    scheme = models.ForeignKey(Scheme)
    D = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    floor_area = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    units = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    build_price_per_m2 = models.FloatField(default=0)
    build_price_per_unit = models.FloatField(default=0)
    affordable_ratio = models.FloatField(default=0) #Actually a percentage field rather than ratio

class RefurbUnit(models.Model):
    scheme = models.ForeignKey(Scheme)
    resale_price = models.FloatField()

    selling_costs = models.FloatField() #This is percentage, and paired with below field which is an absolute figure
    legal_costs = models.FloatField()
    refurbishment_costs = models.FloatField()
    other_costs = models.FloatField()
```

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<scheme_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

from .models import Scheme, NewUnit, RefurbUnit


def index(request):
    scheme_list = Scheme.objects.order_by("-date")[:5]
    context = {"scheme_list": scheme_list}
    return render(request, "value_calculator/index.html", context)

def detail(request, scheme_id):
    scheme = get_object_or_404(Scheme, pk=scheme_id)
    return render(request, "value_calculator/detail.html", {"scheme": scheme})
```

### tests.py

```
import datetime

from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Scheme, NewUnit, RefurbUnit

def create_scheme(name, days=0, new_units=0, refurb_units=0, appraiser=""):
    """Days is an offset value from the current date"""
    time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
    return Scheme.objects.create(name=name, date=time, new_units=new_units, refurb_units=refurb_units, appraiser=appraiser)

class SchemeMethodTests(TestCase):
    def test_get_fields(self):
        """Test that the types and lengths are correct."""
        scheme = create_scheme("Test")
        data = scheme.get_fields()
        print(data)
        self.assertEqual(len(data), 6)
        self.assertEqual(type(data), list)

        for item in data:
            self.assertEqual(type(item), tuple)

class SchemeViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_index_view_with_no_schemes(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('value_calculator:index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "No schemes are available. Please add some via the admin page.")
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['scheme_list'], [])

    def test_index_view_with_past_date(self):
        create_scheme("Past scheme", days=-30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('value_calculator:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context["scheme_list"],
            ["<Scheme: Past scheme>"]
        )

    def test_index_view_with_future_date(self):
        create_scheme("Future scheme", days=30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('value_calculator:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context["scheme_list"],
            ["<Scheme: Future scheme>"]
        )
```

---

## Tutorial's polls app code

### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Choice, Question

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question_text']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ('question_text', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    search_fields = ['question_text']

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

### models.py

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now 

    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic

from .models import Choice, Question

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5] 


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that aren't published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

### tests.py

```
import datetime

from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import Question

def create_question(question_text, days):
    """
    Creates a question with the given `question_text` published the given
    number of `days` offset to now (negative for questions published
    in the past, positive for questions that have yet to be published).
    """
    time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
    return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text,
                                   pub_date=time)


class QuestionViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_index_view_with_no_questions(self):
        """
        If no questions exist, an appropriate message should be displayed.
        """
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

    def test_index_view_with_a_past_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the past should be displayed on the
        index page.
        """
        create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question.>']
        )

    def test_index_view_with_a_future_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the future should not be displayed on
        the index page.
        """
        create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.",
                            status_code=200)
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])

    def test_index_view_with_future_question_and_past_question(self):
        """
        Even if both past and future questions exist, only past questions
        should be displayed.
        """
        create_question(question_text="Past question.", days=-30)
        create_question(question_text="Future question.", days=30)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question.>']
        )

    def test_index_view_with_two_past_questions(self):
        """
        The questions index page may display multiple questions.
        """
        create_question(question_text="Past question 1.", days=-30)
        create_question(question_text="Past question 2.", days=-5)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(
            response.context['latest_question_list'],
            ['<Question: Past question 2.>', '<Question: Past question 1.>']
        )


class QuestionMethodTests(TestCase):
    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() should return False for questions whose
        pub_date is in the future.
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertEqual(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)

    def test_was_published_recently_with_old_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() should return False for questions whose
        pub_date is older than 1 day.
        """
        time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        old_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertEqual(old_question.was_published_recently(), False)

    def test_was_published_recently_with_recent_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() should return True for questions whose
        pub_date is within the last day.
        """
        time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        recent_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertEqual(recent_question.was_published_recently(), True)

class QuestionIndexDetailTests(TestCase):
    def test_detail_view_with_a_future_question(self):
        """
        The detail view of a question with a pub_date in the future should
        return a 404 not found.
        """
        future_question = create_question(question_text='Future question.',
                                          days=5)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:detail',
                                   args=(future_question.id,)))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)

    def test_detail_view_with_a_past_question(self):
        """
        The detail view of a question with a pub_date in the past should
        display the question's text.
        """
        past_question = create_question(question_text='Past Question.',
                                        days=-5)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:detail',
                                   args=(past_question.id,)))
        self.assertContains(response, past_question.question_text,
                            status_code=200)
```

Also, I'm running Linux Mint 17.2 and PostgreSQL 9.3.9.

Comment: There's far too much code here. Why have you posted the views and the tests, when this error is happening in the admin?

Comment: I posted all of the code just to be sure that I wasn't missing out anything relevant (even though the views and tests are unlikely to be useful information).

Comment: This can only be a migration issue. Have you tried `manage.py makemigrations value_calculator`?

Comment: I've just tried it and got `No changes detected in app 'value_calculator'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was with my database in PostgreSQL, although unfortunately I don't know what exactly went wrong. I simply dropped and re-created it with `dropdb` and `createdb`, then ran `manage.py migrate`; my assumption that `manage.py flush` would clear absolutely everything was faulty.

Thanks to Daniel Roseman for leading me to the solution by pointing out that it could only be a migration issue.